# What kinds of limits does localization of commutative rings reflect?

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-picture, ac.commutative-algebra, localization

Localization of commutative rings is a left exact left adjoint, so it behaves nicely with plenty of things. Local-to-global principles are also abundant in commutative algebra, and I thought some of them might actually be reflecting limits in disguise - that some types of limits in localizations must arise from limits in the original ring. Looking at localization as the tensor product of a symmetric monoidal category does not tell me much.

I did not give this much thought and I don't know much commutative algebra, so I hope it's not too stupid/basic to ask here. What inspired it was Nagata's lemma which says an element is prime iff it's either a unit or a prime in some localization. (Thought along the line of prime ideals as regular epis into integral domains.)

So, what kind of (co)limits does localization of commutative rings reflect?

Comment: You can't really expect a single localisation functor to reflect anything. For instance, inverting $0$ is an example of localisation.

Comment: I don't understand what functor you're naming with the phrase "localization of commutative rings." Do you mean the localization functor on modules or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the fundamental results in commutative algebra is the following:

> Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Then $M = 0$ if and only if $M_\mathfrak{m} = 0$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m} \triangleleft A$.

You can think of it as a local-to-global principle if you like. Regardless, it follows that:

> The localisation functor $\mathbf{Mod} (A) \to \prod_{\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{MaxSpec} A} \mathbf{Mod} (A_\mathfrak{m})$ is conservative/faithful.

In particular, $\mathbf{Mod} (A) \to \prod_{\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{MaxSpec} A} \mathbf{Mod} (A_\mathfrak{m})$ reflects finite limits and arbitrary colimits. This should be reminiscent of the fact in sheaf theory that the stalks functor $\mathbf{Sh} (X) \to \prod_{x \in X} \mathbf{Set}$ reflects finite limits and arbitrary colimits.

Comment: Do you know anywhere I could read about the fact that the stalk functor reflects finite limits? I've been thinking about it and can't see why it's true (or what's special about the finite case).

Comment: The domain category has finite limits, and the functor preserves finite limits and is conservative, so it also reflects finite limits.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!